# TFS 2010 work item - how to manage link types

Tags: tfs, workitem

we use TFS 2010 and we have a VCR item with tabs for development tasks and another tab for design tasks.
I want to display only tasks with discipline = "Development" when opening the "link to" window, same for design tasks (Discipline = "requirement").

The LinksControlOptions only filters out link relations and link types.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that "Discpline" is a field on your VCR work item, and not a link type, then this is not possible. You can only filter on LinkType and WorkItemType.